# Problems with layout_height used inside RelativeLayout in android 1.5

Tags: android, android-emulator

This is my layout for an image capture program in android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="420px">
        </SurfaceView>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="@+id/beforeClick"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/clickPanelBK"
        android:paddingTop="6dp" android:paddingBottom="6dp">
        <Button android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/capture_image_goback_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/generalbutton" android:text="@string/back" />
        <Button android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/capture_image_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/clickbutton" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="@+id/afterClick"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/clickPanelBK"
        android:paddingTop="6dp" android:paddingBottom="6dp">
        <Button android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/img_retake"
            android:background="@drawable/generalbutton" android:text="@string/retake" />
        <Button android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/img_save"
            android:text="@string/saveImg" android:background="@drawable/generalbutton" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The last 2 relative layouts are swappable and are aligned fine. Only one of them appear at a time and is changed on a button click. Anyway, The problem here is, I have to mention the layout_height of surface view in px or dp. If I give layout_height as  fill_parent, the view appears very small, 35% of width and height. Can anyone please give me a solution ?

Comment: See here for a sample project that uses a layout_height of fill_parent with a `SurfaceView`: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Preview/

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout had many bugs in 1.5 :(